RankMath redirect error caused by use of regex
I changed the WP permalink structure for my site and have been using RankMath's redirect feature but I've just realised an issue.
Previously the URL structure was:
website.com/category/(sometimes subcategory)/post-title
After the permalink change, the URL structure is now:
website.com/post-title
On RankMath, using the regex function, the source URL is set to /category/(.*) while the destination URL is website/$1. This correctly redirects the old URLs to the new URLs.
However, I've just realised that when you go into the archive page for a particular category to browse other stories in that category, you can only ever see the first page. Subsequent pages, because the URL becomes website.com/category/2/, automatically redirects to the general archive.
Is there a way to fix this?

Perhaps ask on [wordpress.se]?

I think what you are looking for is this:
^/category/(.+)/(.+)$

Basically it has to beign with "/category/" -> ^/category/
Followed by any characters (including numbers) with the length 1-infinity -> (.+)
Followed by "/"
Followed by any characters (including numbers) with the length 1-infinity -> (.+)
This is okay -> /category/(sometimes subcategory)/post-title
This is also okay -> /category/(sometimes subcategory)/post-title/abc
If you want to prevent this you could use
^/category/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$

"([^/]+)" this means any characters but "/"
If you want to use a visual regex this one is great (Note: You can also test regex expressions its great)
Edit: Go to RankMath -> Redirections and edit your redirection rule (add a condition to apply the redirection if the Request URL isnt mathing
